# How to make value type required in ASP.NET MVC validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Good day!

I've a model that is binded from JSON request, say like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public bool isSomeFeatureEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

And controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Submit(MyModel request)
{   
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ..
    }
    else
    {
        ..
    }
}
```

When I post empty JSON object to this action (`{}`) it will be valid with `isSomeFeatureEnabled=false`. But I want this field 'required' in terms that it should be set always in particular value (true\false).

I can make this field nullable and put `[Required]` on it, but the field is not really nullable per model logic.

The same story with `int`, `double` and `DateTime` fields.

I use ASP.NET MVC 3 and default setting of:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = true
```

Shouldn't it work for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think making this field nullable and also making it `Required` is the best shot for now. As the book states, . Otherwise, you can write your own attribute, make the validate method return false when passed in `value = default(T)`

Answer (score 2):

Given the update that the JSON is coming from a 3rd party API and you have no influence on how it is formed; it looks like the nullable is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is not about UI, but about model binding/validation. As I stated in my original question data is comming `from JSON request`, empty request is `{}` (`isSomeFeatureEnabled` is not specified at all). I want to force validation in this case. In other words -- consumer of my JSON actions _should_ specify this field even it is `false`.

Comment: If you don't get anything from the JSON request, have you tried debugging the UI to see why the value isn't set? I think the UI is important to see why and what gets when returned. What control is the property bound to for example in the UI? If it is bound to a checkbox is the checkbox properly initialized? Is the model property initialized before it was sent to the view? Could be a few reasons I guess why you are not getting anything back in the JSON request. If you got no access or control at all over the UI a nullable might be your only choice.

Comment: That's JSON API, so UI is in 3rd party application/website. I should mention that clearly in the original question. It seems I should use nullable and Required attribute.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize, that's why I assumed you can modify how it is sending the JSON originally. In that case it certainly looks like nullable is the way to go. At least you have a workaround.